# change account's main domain in directadmin

Tags: users, domain-name, accounts

**Before anything I should acknowledge that my question was not understandable enough. So I totally edited that**

I have a VPS with DirectAdmin control panel.

One of my users had registered with domain1.com. Now he had decided to change his domain. That's all he is going to do. **NO** files, databases, username, email accounts are changed. The only change is the with the domain name.

**Is there a way to change an account's primary domain name in DirectAdmin?**

Comment: [Administration panels are off topic](http://serverfault.com/help/on-topic). [Even the presence of an administration panel on a system,](http://meta.serverfault.com/q/6538/118258) because they [take over the systems in strange and non-standard ways, making it difficult or even impossible for actual system administrators to manage the servers normally](http://meta.serverfault.com/a/3924/118258), and tend to indicate low-quality questions from *users* with insufficient knowledge for this site.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would expect http://your.server.com:2222/CMD_CHANGE_DOMAIN?domain=domain1.com to work.

Comment: The account doesn't want to stay with domain1.com. He wants to move to a new domain domain2.com but without losing any data or settings. In fact, the account only wants to change its domain. Nothing else.

Comment: That's what the command CHANGE_DOMAIN does, it changes the domain. It changed the domain you give it to a domain it will ask you for. You need to be logged into DA as the user that owns domain1. DA will prompt you to give it the domain name you want to change it to. It will then adjust the DNS and apache confs renaming domain 1 to whatever domain2 you provide to it.

Comment: Yes, thank you. And here's the HowTo using DirectAdmin interface: 1. Login as **owner of the account**, not as admin. 2. Go to `Domain Setup` 4. Go to `Change a Domain Name` 3. Simply enter the new domain name in the text box and submit the Change button :)

Comment: JUST as an FYI for anyone reading this at a later date, "Go to Change a Domain name" does not always appear as a linked option to the user. That depends upon the DA skin you you have assigned to them. Earlier versions of the default skin did not, some of the simpler skins available don't. The url CMD_CHANGE_DOMAIN *should* always work regardless of what skin you are using and of course as an admin you can always temporarily assign the "power user" skin to the user that needs to make a domain name change.